# Laravel : How access laravel app from local network

Tags: laravel, networking, localhost, share

I have laravel app on localhost server, I want to share it to the local network via wamp server, I looked at posts here and did most of actions like :

change httpd-vhosts.conf to :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

create new rule in firewall system for TCP.
change C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host to :

```
#127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.0.105 attendance
```

add Listen 192.168.0.105:80 to httpd.conf

and not solved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must run serve command on LAN ip address, Try this:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Then you can access the app from other device connectd to the LAN by typing your local ip address instead of `0.0.0.0` in the browser
for example if your local ip is `192.168.1.15` then the url will be:
http://192.168.1.15:8000

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `php artisan serve --port={numberyoulike}` to start a server, and in another device, you can access your laravel app.